# How do I save a current date/time for a DATETIME column in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a DATETIME column called last_profile_update. I need to update it with a current time. I have the following code:

```
user = User.new
user.last_profile_update = Date.today
user.save
```

but it does not work.

Comment: What is the data type for the last_profile_update column?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Perhaps a way to simplify that code:

```
user = User.create(:last_profile_update => Time.now)
```

Comment: I would use DateTime.current

Answer (score 17):

It could be done with

```
user.touch(:last_profile_update)
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it was `Time.now`

```
user = User.new
user.last_profile_update = Time.now
user.save
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be done with:

```
user.last_profile_update = Date.today.to_datetime
```

Answer (score 1):

```
User.create({:last_profile_update=>Time.now})
```